# How to show 2 items in my @Html.DropDownList?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a @Html.DropDownList, but I neeed to show my items like this:
"SiglaBanca - NameBanca" in my dropdownlist when I catch the items in my database.

I'm using this code in my controller:

```
var aplicationBanca = new BancaAplication();
        ViewData["ListOfBancas"] = new SelectList(aplicationBanca.ShowAll(), "BancaId", "NameBanca");
```

in my view:

```
        @Html.DropDownList("BancaId", (SelectList)ViewData["ListOfBancas"], "Banca/Organization")
```

I need to show in my dropdown the SiglaBanca and NameBanca.

Answer (score 0):

Create a ViewModel `FullBanca` (or w/e) in your mvc project that will have a list of elements that each element consist "SiglaBanca - NameBanca"

do your mapping to this view model in the function within the controller and to your View send this ViewModel .

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a list just before your @html.DropDownList

```
var ddList = new SelectList....
var ddList.add(new selectItem("--All--",0));
```

and finally pass it to your syntax

```
Html.DropDownList("ShowType",ddList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have like this -

```
SelectList list = ViewData["ListOfBancas"];
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedValue, new SelectList(list.Select(item => new { Text = item.Text + " - " + item.Value, Value = item.Value}), "Value", "Text"),"--Select--")
```